# Find range of a sentence in word file by win32com

Tags: python-3.x, ms-word, win32com

Here is a word file, like the following picture

[image: Example]

If I want to insert a bookmark to the sentence `I like C++ too`
and I use the following code

```py
from win32com.client import Dispatch
wordapp = Dispatch("Word.Application")
wordapp.visible = False
worddoc = wordapp.Documents.Open("/text.docx")

worddoc.Bookmarks.Add("Name of bookmark", "range")
```

However, in `worddoc.Bookmarks.Add("Name of bookmark", "range")`

the `range` of sentence `I like C++ too` is unknown.

Is there any way the acquire the range of the sentence `I like C++ too`?

Thanks

Comment: Use Word's built-in `Find` functionality. When a search term is found, `Find.Execute` returns that `Range`.